# Creating a Concrete texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I recently attempted to create a concrete texture, but it turned into more of a stucco texture.

I have no idea on how to continue. I am looking for the concrete to have a texture with inset cracks on it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try using a different browser, also try uploading the images to imgur.com, then you can add the link. The idea is that the images show as part of your post making it easier to get help.

Comment: Can you add a link to your cracks image texture and/or expand the node group for it?  Also, how are you inputting you UV map?